# Delete child table record in sql

Tags: sql

Suppose we have two tables in sql one is parent and the second one is child(foreign key constraints).how can we delete the data   without drop their constraint?

Comment: This may require product spesific commands, so revealing your DBMS is important.

Comment: what do you mean by `delete data without drop their constraint`?
do you want to delete data from both the tables or just the referenced table ?And what are your criteria for deletion of data?

Comment: Set the foreign key column to null before delete.  But you'll have orphaned data.

Comment: Using `CASCADE DELETE` maybe?

Comment: Or deleting all children first, then delete the parent row.